# XGboost model consistently obtaining 100% accuracy?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, cross-validation, xgboost

I'm working with Airbnb's data, available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/airbnb-recruiting-new-user-bookings) on Kaggle , and predicting the countries users will book their first trips to with an XGBoost model and almost 600 features in R. Running the algorithm through 50 rounds of 5-fold cross validation, I obtained 100% accuracy each time. After fitting the model to the training data, and predicting on a held out test set, I also obtained 100% accuracy. These results can't be real. There must be something wrong with my code, but so far I haven't been able to figure it out. I've included a section of my code below. It's based on this [article](https://rpubs.com/mharris/multiclass_xgboost). Following along with the article (using the article's data + copying the code), I receive similar results. However applying it to Airbnb's data, I consistently obtain 100% accuracy. I have no clue what is going on. Am I using the xgboost package incorrectly? Your help and time is appreciated.

```
# set up the data  
# train is the data frame of features with the target variable to predict
full_variables <- data.matrix(train[,-1]) # country_destination removed
full_label <- as.numeric(train$country_destination) - 1 

# training data 
train_index <- caret::createDataPartition(y = train$country_destination, p = 0.70, list = FALSE)
train_data <- full_variables[train_index, ]
train_label <- full_label[train_index[,1]]
train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = train_data, label = train_label)

# test data 
test_data <- full_variables[-train_index, ]
test_label <- full_label[-train_index[,1]]
test_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = test_data, label = test_label)

# 5-fold CV
params <- list("objective" = "multi:softprob",
               "num_class" = classes,
               eta = 0.3, 
               max_depth = 6)
cv_model <- xgb.cv(params = params,
               data = train_matrix,
               nrounds = 50,
               nfold = 5,
               early_stop_round = 1,
               verbose = F,
               maximize = T,
               prediction = T)

# out of fold predictions 
out_of_fold_p <- data.frame(cv_model$pred) %>% mutate(max_prob = max.col(., ties.method = "last"),label = train_label + 1)
head(out_of_fold_p)

# confusion matrix
confusionMatrix(factor(out_of_fold_p$label), 
                factor(out_of_fold_p$max_prob),
                mode = "everything")
```

Sample of the data I used for this can be found here by running this code:

```
library(RCurl)
x < getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loshita/Senior_project/master/train.csv")
y <- read.csv(text = x)
```

Comment: Unless the code you provide is incomplete, **you don't actually use your test data for model predictions**. You only assess the in-sample error/accuracy. See [this link](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/05/using-caret-to-compare-models.html) for a worked-through XGBoost + `caret` example, where the model is fit to the training data, and then used for predictions using the test data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the `train_users_2.csv.zip` available on kaggle then the problem is you are not removing the `country_destination` from the train data set since it is at position `16` and not `1`.

```
which(colnames(train) == "country_destination")
#output
16
```

`1` is `id` which is unique for every observation and should also be removed.

```
length(unique(train[,1)) == nrow(train)
#output
TRUE
```

When I run your code with the following modification:

```
full_variables <- data.matrix(train[,-c(1, 16)]) 

  library(xgboost)

params <- list("objective" = "multi:softprob",
               "num_class" = length(unique(train_label)),
               eta = 0.3, 
               max_depth = 6)
cv_model <- xgb.cv(params = params,
                   data = train_matrix,
                   nrounds = 50,
                   nfold = 5,
                   early_stop_round = 1,
                   verbose = T,
                   maximize = T,
                   prediction = T)
```

I obtain a test error during cross validation of 0.12 with the above settings.

```
out_of_fold_p <- data.frame(cv_model$pred) %>% mutate(max_prob = max.col(., ties.method = "last"),label = train_label + 1)

head(out_of_fold_p[,13:14], 20)
#output
   max_prob label
1         8     8
2        12    12
3        12    10
4        12    12
5        12    12
6        12    12
7        12    12
8        12    12
9         8     8
10       12     5
11       12     2
12        2    12
13       12    12
14       12    12
15       12    12
16        8     8
17        8     8
18       12     5
19        8     8
20       12    12
```

So to sum up, you did not remove the `y` from the `x`.

EDIT: after downloading the true train set and playing around I can say the accuracy is really 100% in 5 fold CV. Not just that this is achieved by only 22 features (and possibly less).

```
model <- xgboost(params = params,
                   data = train_matrix,
                   nrounds = 50,
                   verbose = T,
                   maximize = T)
```

This model also gets 100% accuracy on the test set:

```
pred <- predict(model, test_matrix)
pred <- matrix(pred, ncol=length(unique(train_label)), byrow = TRUE)
out_of_fold_p <- data.frame(pred) %>% mutate(max_prob = max.col(., ties.method = "last"),label = test_label + 1)

sum(out_of_fold_p$max_prob != out_of_fold_p$label) #0 errors
```

Now lets check which features are discriminatory:

```
xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix = xgb.importance(colnames(train_matrix), model))
```

[image]

now if you run xgb.cv with just these features:

```
train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = train_data[,which(colnames(train_data) %in% xgboost::xgb.importance(colnames(train_matrix), model)$Feature)], label = train_label)

set.seed(1)
cv_model <- xgb.cv(params = params,
                   data = train_matrix,
                   nrounds = 50,
                   nfold = 5,
                   early_stop_round = 1,
                   verbose = T,
                   maximize = T,
                   prediction = T)
```

You will also attain 100% accuracy on the test folds

The reason is partly in the very big disbalance of the classes:

```
table(train_label)
train_label
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11 
  3  10  12  13  36  16  19 856   7  73   3 451
```

and the fact the minor classes are very easily distinguished by 1 dummy variable:

```
gg <- data.frame(train_data[,which(colnames(train_data) %in% xgb.importance(colnames(train_matrix), model)$Feature)], label = as.factor(train_label))

gg %>%
  as.tibble() %>%
  select(1:9, 11, 12, 15:21, 23) %>%
  gather(key, value, 1:18) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x = label))+
  facet_grid(key ~ value) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

based on the distribution of 0/1 of the 22 most important features it looks to me any tree model would be able to achieve pretty good accuracy if not 100% accuracy.

One would expect the classes 0 and 10 would be problematic for 5 - fold CV since there is a chance all the subjects would fall into one fold so that the model would not know about them at least in that instance. Which would be a  possibility if one designed CV by random sampling. This does not happen with xgb.cv:

```
lapply(cv_model$folds, function(x){
  table(train_label[x])})
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, the error you get is still the *in-sample (training data-based) error*, and not the *out-of-sample (test data-based) error*. I thought OP is interested in assessing the performance on the test data. You have shown that training the model using the test data achieves an accuracy of 88% on the test data.

Comment: The error is 5 - fold CV error obtained by `xgb.cv`. The `pred` item in `cv_model` contains the test fold predictions with rows in the same order as the data. Although the train fold error is very close to the test fold error in this case. This can be seen from `?xgb.cv`.

Comment: But you never use the hold-out test data `test_data` for any prediction, or am I missing something obvious? The `pred` item contains predictions based on the training data, and the error is the 5-fold CV error based on the training data.

Comment: @Maurits Evers you are absolutely correct, the error is based on the data set aside for training but even so, since the predictions are performed on data not seen by the model I trust this is refereed to as test error even though it is not based on validation but rather on cross validation. I just wanted to point out the error in Lisas code, which would lead to 100% validation accuracy since the `y` would have been used to predict `y` during validation also. I edited the post to make it clear the test error I refer to is based on CV.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @missuse, and I agree with everything you said. I think Hastie and Tibshirani make a point somewhere in EoSL that in the case of data scarcity, the process of splitting data into a training and testing/validation set can lead to poor predictive models; instead using CV on the full data controls for overfitting, and results in a model with small CV prediction errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The train data I used in my code though is not the original 'train_users_2'. It's a different data frame I created with engineered and one hot encoded features, with 'country_destination' or 'y' in the first column. User 'id' is also removed from this data frame. Sorry, should have been more clear about the data.

Comment: I uploaded a sample (1%) of the data to my github account.

Comment: I added to the bottom of my question the code you can run to download the data. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: @Lisa O I added some insights. In short I think your model does have 100% accuracy.

Comment: @missuse Thank you for your help - I really appreciate this!